# *SOS Window replacement in old house (1890)

Tags: repair, windows, window-frame, house, advice

2 sets of windows on walls adjacent to each other (same setup/dimension). Each window "set" consist of 3 small windows.

When this company man came to install windows, hardly looked at them, claimed he couldn't as it's structural, floor would collapse & need an engineer.

He hadn't looked & they sent people back when 1st evaluating & said it'll work. No one looked behind a frame or anything.

They had me contact their engineer who replied to 1 pic sent (didn't look at everything) & said just for them to come measure is $1400 (people already came to measure, windows made custom, Idk).

Their concern:

- Middle "posts" between small windows might support header & need to restructure wall if removed.

I had a contractor come (not through them). He said:

- 1 window set definitely not structural/load bearing wall but then said the other was. He only made this judgement from a video shown that's it.

I found:

- Each middle post is a cut piece of wood that sits partially (not fully) on dry wall (see pic).

How is it possible this cut wood is load bearing/supports header but doesn't extend to any surface aside from drywall partially?

I've only found 1 wall load bearing beam(s) to left of 1 of the window sets. Stud finder confirmed this. I think if any load bearing beam either it's on the sides of the sets not from the middle "posts".

Can anyone please confirm if middle posts arent load bearing or if they are somehow? Or is it the beam outside the set as it seems?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se], please take the [tour]. Then, please [edit] your question to get to the point. There's a lot of backstory, and I got lost by about the 5th paragraph. Please focus on the critical details, then, if you desire, you can give the story at the end. Also, please focus on asking a clear and _specific_ question so we can give you an answer (or two). Here are some tips on [how to ask a good question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I’m not an engineer; remember that you paid nothing for this. That looks like a skinny header and a fairly wide span. I wouldn’t be surprised if the posts were actually needed. Good news is that you have everything apart, so stuffing in a bigger header is pretty easy. You will need professional design for sizing. (Unless you just buy a 4x28…)

Comment: Why are you saying that the center posts don't **"extend to anything"**? It looks to me like they're sitting on solid wood supported by 2x4 stud wall.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking or trying to do.  Is it to replace the three windows, currently with some support between them, with a single picture window or perhaps 3 windows with totally non-structural muntins between them (essentially a visually broken up picture window) ?   If that is the objective ... why?   Why don't you just put in three windows?  I don't think anyone can calculate from your photos but it sure looks like the framing below and above them and the posts between them were all designed to work together.

Comment: @JimmyFix-it apologies for it not being clear, I realize how it's confusing but the center/middle posts are actually cut through the window sill (the white sill), I posted a pic I know isn't the best picture but it's shows under the center/middle posts &how it goes through the sill as mentioned & is now just sitting on the drywall. I'm going to take the frame cover over to see if there's an additional piece behind it as that'll answer if it truly has anything sitting of the 2x4 part as you pointed out.

Comment: @jay613 my apologies I realize my post wasn't clear & very confusing. I'm going to try to edit it, I was afraid if I explained too much I'd lose people's interest. The goal is to replace the 3 windows with 1 window that's of the same measurements/dimensions of the existing 3-window set& structure. The frames are rotted beyond belief as well as replacing them is a neccesity but would be ideal if we could accomplish the 1 window goal since the current windows are so small, it doesn't bring in much light or anything.

Comment: Urg I edited the post & it didn't save, I give up

Answer (score 2):

Because what you're shopping for, is not what you need.

There's a huge aftermarket industry out there for "replacement windows" that is borderline scam, in my opinion. It's highly profitable and aggressively marketed, and you probably got sucked into that sales funnel.

So these window products are made at a factory and include an enormous wrap-around frame, which is to aid in shipping the window without it taking damage. It's much like the way some modern doors are sold "with frame". These are all great for speeding new construction, but they're a misfit for an older home where the frame was constructed in place.

They're absolutely right, the large frames of their factory made window products will conflict with the structural wood in your walls.

So you just need an old-school window guy who can work with traditional sash windows.

These guys you're talking to aren't that at all, and don't want any part of that work, they're just "one-trick pony" types who only know how to sell and install those replacement window assemblies.  All their efforts will be to force your old house into their sales model. They are not window experts, just "selling one solution" specialists.

Comment: I appreciate your feedback. However, theyre custom made windows they measured to make & all. I'm wondering if the claim of the middle posts supporting the header is true? I don't believe it is & if it's not (the other window set is confirmed to be good) then I can finally just replace them with the current structure rather than have to get into a hefty expense of restructuring the entire wall for the 1 window set.

Comment: I agree with @Harper, if an engineer (and 2 different installers) is/are telling you that the center posts are needed for support you should believe that over the word of the window salesmen. If you just left the center posts you could put in 3 separate new windows and it would not need re-engineering or any alteration; it would look great that way IMO.